# Fontawesome didn't work in my react application

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I installed font-awesome via npm.

```
"dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.15",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.7.2",
        "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.4",
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "react": "^16.8.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.2",
        "react-scripts": "2.1.5"
    },
```

But how can i use icon in my app.

```
<i className="fas fa-home" ></i>
                        <b> Trang chủ </b>
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react), it looks like you first need import each icon that you want to use and register it with the Font Awesome library. Then when you want to use an icon, import `FontAwesomeIcon` as a React component and then render it as such.

For example:

In App.js:

```js
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faHome } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(faHome)
```

Then in your component file:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

export default props => {
    return (
        <span>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="home"/>
            <b>Trang chu</b>
        </span>
    )
}
```